# Distribution of Azure Functions

Tags: installation, azure-functions, software-distribution

From the product development/ISV point of view, I wanted to understand if there is any recommended approach to create a Distributable package (installable) for Azure Functions. I found one post on [TechNet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51580.re-distributing-azure-functions.aspx) but its very old (2017).

Also, is there any marketplace for Azure functions?

Thanks

Comment: we have tested the distributing azure functions  in our local environment with last version of visual code 2019 and the documented steps were working pretty fine for fine me & i hope this should work for you as well. 
Could you please help us with more insight what exactly you are looking about  "marketplace for Azure functions" ?

Comment: This looks like similar to what I was referring to the marketplace:

https://serverlesslibrary.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Zip deployment for Azure Functions" option could be possibly useful and there are few more options mentioned under the "deploy" section of the documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push

This looks similar to what I was referring to the marketplace:

https://serverlesslibrary.net/

Answer (score -1):

Thank you [Venkatesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15968720/venkateshdodda-mt), Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

the above suggested steps in the shared article are working fine by the distributing azure functions in our local environment with last version of visual code 2019 and the documented steps were working pretty fine and this should work for you as well.

Comment: Please post this as a comment in future, not answer.